# Probability Sample Space Question

Tags: probability

I'll be taking Intro. to Statistics class next week and I'm currently doing a preview on the course materials by watching Prof. Leonard's youtube videos on probability, and I'm a little confused on the following question (in his video) and I'll appreciate it very much if anyone can help me out.

**Question:** Find the probability that if a couple has 3 kids, two will be boys. Assuming equals chance of Boy/Girl.

**Solution:** In Prof. Leonard's video, he solved the question by first finding the sample space of the procedure: Let $B$ represent Boy, and $G$ represent Girl, then sample space is

{$BBB, GGG, BBG, BGB, BGG, GGB, GBG, GBB$}.

Since the couple want two boys and one girl, then the probability is: $3 \div 8 \times 100 = 37.5 \%$.

**My Confusion:** The above solution has a sample space size of $8$ in which the order matters. However, based on my understanding of the problem, the Event is simply having two boys and a girl where order doesn't matter. So in this case shouldn't the sample space be:

{All Boys, All Girls, Two Boys one Girl, Two Girls one Boy}

Since $BBG$ is the same as $BGB$ etc... So the probability of the Event is $1 \div4 \times 100 = 25\%$ ?

I understand that the sample space in Prof. Leonard's solution covers all possible outcomes, however, the question given does not specify that the order of Boy and Girl has to be in a specific order, thus imo, there are only four possible outcomes.

Comment: The point of breaking up the sample space that way is to ensure each of its elements are equally likely.

Comment: You misconception is that for all boys and all girls, there is only one way to get that. For two boy and a girl and two girls and a boy, there are three different ways and therefore three times more likely an outcome. This doesn't have to be specified, it's just one of the characteristics of determining a sample space.